# How To increase th width when parent div has overflow scroll?

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

How to increase the th width in the above fiddle, when parent div has overflow scroll,
I tried to increase the width of each column using jQuery but the width of the th remains same.
But if I try to increase the width of div tag inside the th then the size of column increases, but I need the width for th instead of div

if I set th width to 500px nothing changes:

```
<th width="500px">&nbsp;</th>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rathnakar076/wcwa037c/)

```html
<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table border="1" id="Sample">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th width="200px" class="thead selector noedit">&nbsp;</th>
        <th width="200px" data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead">
          <div style="width:100px">Category ID</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="30" class="thead ">
          <div>ID2</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="13" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:130px">ID3</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID4</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="21" class="thead">
          <div style="width:210px">ID5</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID6</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID7</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID8</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID9</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID11</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID12</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID13</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID14</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID15</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID16</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID17</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID18</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID19</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID21</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID22</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID23</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID24</div>
        </th>
        <th data-field="" data-length="10" class="thead ">
          <div style="width:100px">ID25</div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: css cannot do this, you need javascript to detect when div has to show a scroll bar and retrieve its width.

Comment: can you send me how to control th width using jquery??

Comment: give it a try, then one can help & explain where you are failing ;)

Comment: ok,Thanks @G-Cyr